Корректный способ удаления QMenu
Есть виджет, который создает контекстное меню, примерно таким образом:
void Widget::onContextMenuRequested(const QPoint position)
{
    auto menu = new QMenu(this);

    menu->addAction(...);
    menu->addAction(...);
    menu->addAction(...);

    menu->popup(m_view->horizontalHeader()->viewport()->mapToGlobal(position));
}

Вопрос следующий: как корректно удалить это меню? Ему назначен parent (this), но тогда получается, что пока текущее окно не удалится, все экземпляры меню будут висеть в оперативной памяти. Создавать меню на стеке и показывать его при помощи exec не вариант, так как это блокирует поток выполнения.
Нашел для себя такой вариант решения
connect(menu, &QMenu::aboutToHide, menu, &QObject::deleteLater);

Однако такой вариант кажется мне некрасивым. Есть ли какие то рекомендации по очищению памяти от неиспользуемых menu? Возможно фреймворк делает это самостоятельно?

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/objecttrees.html

Предлагаю решить проблему в корне и вместо создания меню на каждый вызов создать его один раз при создании виджета/окна родителя и просто показывать одно и то же меню

Вам нужно контекстное меню именно как асинхронное? Если нет, то мспользуйте QMenu::exec. Меню можно будет удалить прямо в теле функции, куда вернется управление, после того как меню будет закрыто.

В большинстве случаев создание и удаление меню - более трудоемкая вещь, чем его содержание. QAction, которые при этом остаются "живыми", более затратны. Исключением являются случаи когда набор элементов чрезвычайно динамичен (не проще иметь несколько меню или изменять существующее?) или количество экземпляров родителя огромно.
connect(menu, &QMenu::aboutToHide, menu, &QObject::deleteLater);

Этот паттерн вполне корректен. Удалять привязанный событиями объект когда попало нельзя. Тут он удаляется при первой возможности после закрытия.

Здравствуйте, ваш подход (иметь несколько меню или изменять существующее) вполне себе валиден, ситуация такова, что нужно отображать разное меню на разные строчки в модели, например там могут быть дефолтные для системы данные, которые не подлежат удалению, или клик может быть произведен по пустому полю в таблице, каждый раз вставлять и удалять в меню Action'ы не очень удобно. Хорошим вариантом мне здесь кажется делать ненужные в определенном контексте Action'ы disabled либо hidden, сами же Action'ы существуют в течении всего жизненного цикла виджета.

@ДенисГурков Был еще подход "склеивания" нескольких меню в одно, но я сейчас не помню, поддерживает ли это Qt (родные API форточек и X11 поддерживали).
